# how to remove www from redirect url in nginx conf

Tags: nginx

Below is my nginx conf, how to remove www. from redirect url.
right now when i am entering url [www.platform.iamwoken.com/](http://www.platform.iamwoken.com/) its redirecting to https://www.platform.iamwoken.com/ which is wrong
i need to redirect it to https://platform.iamwoken.com/

```
server_tokens off;

server {
    if ($host ~ (platform.iamwoken.com|www.platform.iamwoken.com)) {
        return 301 https://platform.iamwoken.com;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name platform.iamwoken.com www.platform.iamwoken.com;
        return 301 https://platform.iamwoken.com;


}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

        server_name platform.iamwoken.com www.platform.iamwoken.com;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

        # Disable SSL
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1;

        # Optimise cipher suites
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        # Enable HSTS
        add_header Strict-Transaport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

        # SSL sessions
        #ssl_session_cache shared:devplatform.iamwoken.com:40m;
       # ssl_session_tickets on;

        # Skip buffering for static files
        sendfile on;

        location /static/ {
                access_log off;

                add_header Cache-Control public;
                add_header Pragma public;
                add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
                expires 1m;
                root /home/ubuntu/wokencrm;
        }

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
                # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}
```

how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

use below NGiNX block to redirect www to non-www

```
server {
server_name www.platform.iamwoken.com;
return 301 $scheme://platform.iamwoken.com$request_uri;
}
```

Restart the nginx web-server and test the URL in browser. It will work as expected.

Comment: server_tokens off;

server {
server_name www.platform.iamwoken.com;
return 301 $scheme://platform.iamwoken.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    if ($host ~ (platform.iamwoken.com|www.platform.iamwoken.com)) {
        return 301 https://platform.iamwoken.com;
    } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name platform.iamwoken.com www.platform.iamwoken.com;
        return 301 https://platform.iamwoken.com;


}